# What is the difference between how dictionary and list datastructures appear in memory?

Tags: python

For instance, if I was to create the following code:

```
a_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
a_dict = { 0: 'this', 1 : 'is', 2 : 'a', 3 : 'sentence'}
```

then typing in the command prompt

```
>a_list[0]
```

yields

```
>'this'
```

as does

```
>a_dict[0]
```

yield

```
>'this'
```

Is there anything wrong with saying that a list is a type of dictionary if used strictly in the above manner so that the keys are the integers beginning at 0? Functionally they seem the same to me *at this level of abstraction*, so what is the difference in space that the - I assume functionally - equivalent structures take up in memory, and the speed in which we can access the values in python? A dictionary is a mathematical map, and a map that maps the positive integers to values is mathematically equivalent to a list. Am I wrong in saying given the above restrictions they are functionally the same *at this level of abstraction*. So what is the practical or computational difference in python?

Comment: Did you read http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange and http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict?  These two sections seem to cover **all** of the differences between these types.  Perhaps you could **update** your question with the specific words or phrases which confused you.

Comment: Thankyou, I will certainly have a look.

Comment: As others have noted, there are many implementation and performance differences. But I would say the fundamental difference between the [abstract data structures] "list" and "dictionary" is whether members have a well-defined successor: a list's items are fully ordered, but a dict's are not. Of course order(s) can be added (for example, sort(d.keys(), OrderedDict, etc), but arguably that's no longer a "pure" dictionary/map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python dictionaries are not limited to integers as keys - anything that's *hashable* can be keys - strings, tuples, etc. In fact, using integer keys in Python dicts is far from being the most common use.

Python lists can be viewed as simple dynamic arrays (similar to C++'s `std::vector`). On the other hand, dicts are implemented as hash tables (`std::unordered_map` in the upcoming C++0x standard).

Why not always use dicts instead of lists? Because for many operations lists are **the right data structure for the job** - faster and smaller than dicts. For example, if all you need is a linear list of items you should use a list, not a dict - the list will consume less space, it will be faster in index access and it preserves insertion order. Yes, if you don't care about performance and about order, you can probably live with dicts instead of lists.

---

P.S. In some languages (Lua IIRC), arrays are implemented in terms of hash tables with numeric keys, so the equivalence you're trying to define exists.

Comment: +1. PHP uses associative arrays as has tables and arrays too I think.

Answer (score 1):

[List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure).

[Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Try to not confuse them.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with saying that a list
>   is a type of dictionary in where the
>   keys are the integers beginning at 0?

Because that's factually incorrect. A dictionary can have keys like 0,2,4,6,8,10. A list cannot. A list doesn't have keys. It has indices to elements.

> Functionally they must be the same,

Why? They're not the same. A list is a data structure designed for efficient iteration and sequential access. A dictionary is an implementation of a hash table designed for random access.

> so what is the difference in space
>   that they equivalent structures take
>   up in memory, and the speed in which
>   we can access the values in python

The objects are completely different. The code that's actually executed inside the interpreter when you access or use these types are completely different. They're designed for different purposes.

> So what is the practical or
>   computational difference in python?

You should read up on data structures. Arrays and hash tables have different uses and applications. Python's lists and dictionaries are implementations of these structures and are used for different purposes. The performance characters, abstract data types and applications are completely different.

Comment: Your 0,2,4,6,8,10 example isn't entirely precise. Sparse lists are being used frequently for O(1) access if the range of keys is known and limited.

Comment: That's like a list implemented using a hash table isn't it?

Comment: Logically, I can use a list as a lookup table for a known, bounded set of numeric keys. This is a frequently used methods to speed things up by exchanging space for speed.

Comment: That makes sense although I'd view that as you implementing a custom hash table using a list.

Comment: The way I see it, not all lookup tables are hash tables. "Lookup table" is a general term and "hash table" is one way to implement it. Another way to implement it is with a sparse array, given some constraints on the keys. Another way is with a tree, etc.

Comment: Interesting. I've always used the terms interchangeably. Your distinction is clear though and I think it's time for me to revise my views.

Comment: I'll just add that lookup tables are commonly called "maps" or mappings - both in the C++ world and Python world. In C++ in particular, the only really standard maps (lookup tables) are still RB-Trees, with a hash table being added only in the next standard. In Python, a dict is an instance of a more general concept - mapping types

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the question was "given these assumptions" how are they different. You have simply told me how they are different without taking into consideration the assumptions.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at then. These *are* the differences. The implementations are different, the performance characteristics are different, the common uses are different. Can you rephrase your question so that I can understand what you're driving at?

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking for performance comparisions, in CPython implementation they are close when it comes to certain operations like Get item and Set item etc. Look at [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) explaining the details of time complexity.

But you have to remember that a list is list and dict a dict. You cannot sort a dict, it does not make any sense and you can do that to a list. You insert an item to a list, but to set a key,value pair in the dict. They are different operations.